# How to name vue components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have four components: `comments.vue`, `comments-list.vue`, `comment.vue`, `comment-new.vue`.

`comments.vue` uses other components to display:

1. List of comments (does not have any ajax calls)

   a. Which contains single comment (basically it's just a template with single property)
2. Textarea to send comment (has ajax calls)

`comments.vue` has all logic to load paginated comments

So my question is: is it good separation of responsibilities?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can check this [Vue.js Component Style Guide](https://github.com/pablohpsilva/vuejs-component-style-guide#vue-component-names)

From the guide:

**Vue Component Names**

Each component name must be:

- Meaningful: not over specific, not overly abstract.
- Short: 2 or 3 words.
- Pronounceable: we want to be able talk about them.

Vue component names must also be:

- Custom element spec compliant: include a hyphen, don't use reserved
  names.
- app- namespaced: if very generic and otherwise 1 word, so that it can
  easily be reused in other projects.

**Why?**

The name is used to communicate about the component. So it must be short, meaningful and pronounceable.

**How?**

```
 <!-- recommended -->
<app-header></app-header>
<user-list></user-list>
<range-slider></range-slider>

<!-- avoid -->
<btn-group></btn-group> <!-- short, but unpronounceable. use `button-group` instead -->
<ui-slider></ui-slider> <!-- all components are ui elements, so is meaningless -->
<slider></slider> <!-- not custom element spec compliant -->
```

Comment: Are numbers allowed